# Laravel Agrega un index en ResourceCollection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estoy tratando de crear un API que pueda recibir parámetros para filtrar los resultados.

Al momento de añadir la sentencia where, el resultado del API Cambia.

Este es el controlador:

```
public function index(Request $request) {
    $id_rol = $request->query('id_rol');
    $users = User::all();
    if ($id_rol) {
        $users = $users->where('id_rol', $id_rol);
        info($users);
    }

    return new UserCollection(UserResource::collection($users));
}
```

Mi UserCollection

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class UserCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return ['data' => $this->collection];
    }
}
```

Mi Resource

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use App\Rol;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;

class User extends Resource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'rol' => new RolResource(Rol::find($this->id_rol))
        ];
    }
}
```

Cuando se consume el api sin el filtro `/api/users` Me muestra el json de esta forma:

```
{
"data": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Prueba",
    "email": "prueba@prueba.com",
    "rol": {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Recursos Humanos"
  }, ...]
}
```

Y Cuando añado el filtro `api/users?id_rol=2` Me muestra los resultados añadiendo un index al principio de cada objeto.

```
{
  "data": {
    "1": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Despachador",
      "email": "despachador@despachador.com",
      "rol": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Despachador de Gasolina"
      }
    },
    "3": {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "R2D2",
      "email": "despachador2@despachador.com",
      "rol": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Despachador de Gasolina"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

¿Cómo modifico este comportamiento?

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Cuál es el comportamiento deseado?

Comment: que retorne el json sin que añada un index antes del objeto dentro del json cuando uso la sentencia  `where() `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Añadiendo funcion values()

Lo solucioné de la siguiente manera:

```
    $users = $users->where('id_rol', $id_rol)->values();
```

Answer (score 0):

puede ser que no obtengas el resultado que quieres, por lo que devuelve el controlador..
Por qué no devuelves directamente en el controlador:

```
return UserResource::collection($users);
```

Un saludo.